# How to enable a button only after entering text in textinput

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I want to enable a button only after entering text in textinput? How to achive this? Anybody please help me..

`<mx:TextInput id="UserDetail" x="150" y="66" width="200" height="30"/>`

`<mx:Button id="Click" x="124" y="111" width="220" height="50" 
               cornerRadius="10" fontSize="18" enabled="false"/>`

I want my "Click" button to be enabled after the user fills the userDetail or enter a text in TextInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mx:Button id="Click" x="124" y="111" width="220" height="50" cornerRadius="10" fontSize="18" enabled="{UserDetail.text.length>0}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks codeghost, It perfectly works..Thanks for your reply in a quick time